# I get an error that I don't know for what reason. a file disappears when I run the program

Tags: file, go, operating-system, go-echo

I'm coding in Go, and I created a file handler and a program that prints the value of that file.

However, the file that should be created with file.Filename is deleted when I run it.

I don't know what the reason is, even if I try to debug, the answer doesn't come out, and even if I google it, I don't get the answer.

(64bit windows 10 (WSL2))

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "io/ioutil"
    "os"

    "github.com/labstack/echo"
)

func checkErr(err error) {
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
}

func readFile(filename string) string {
    data, err := ioutil.ReadFile(filename)
    checkErr(err)
    return string(data)
}

func main() {
    e := echo.New()

    e.POST("/file", func(c echo.Context) error {
        file, err := c.FormFile("file")
        checkErr(err)

        src, err := file.Open()
        checkErr(err)
        defer src.Close()

        dst, err := os.Create(file.Filename)
        checkErr(err)
        defer dst.Close()

        _, err = io.Copy(dst, src)
        checkErr(err)

        data := readFile(file.Filename)

        fmt.Println(data)

        return c.String(200, "sd")
    })

    e.Logger.Fatal(e.Start(":5000"))
}
```

Comment: does the file get deleted or is the file empty?

Comment: Try [syncing](https://golang.org/pkg/os/#File.Sync) the file before re-reading it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing that your file exists, but the code that you wrote is reading the file before the changes are ["flushed to disk"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10371017/fsync-vs-write-system-call).

Right here:

```
defer dst.Close()
 _, err = io.Copy(dst, src)
```

Should `Close()` or `Sync()` your writer as soon as possible, otherwise you may read before the write is finished. And since your `readFile()` function isn't re-using the file, you might as well just close (not `Sync()`) it immediately, not deferred

Try this:

```
 _, err = io.Copy(dst, src)
dst.Close()
if err != nil {
  
}
```

There could be an error while copying, but we still want to Close() the file (if there wasn't an error during the `os.Create`, `os.Open,` or `os.OpenFile`...

Comment: Looks to me that you first close the file, before the copy or else you get a race condition.

Comment: Yes. Thats exactly whats going on